# How to download private repo from Dockerfile with bitbucket and golang project

Tags: git, docker, go, bitbucket

I want download a private repository from bitbucket, but get some error

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled
```

here my dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.17 as build

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
  apt install -y git \
  make openssh-client 

WORKDIR /src 

COPY . . 


RUN git config --global url."https://username:app_password@bitbucket.org".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org"
RUN go mod tidy

RUN go build -o user-management
```

Comment: It is *possible* to do this, but generally unwise: see [Bill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72239413/1256452). The reason it is unwise is that there's a secret involved in cloning a private repository: in this case, a user name and password/token/whatever. If you execute the clone from within Docker, that *leaves the secret exposed* to anyone who has access to the Docker image.

Comment: @torek, buildkit allows to mount different types of secrets for a specific run instruction. They dont persist and are not visible in the history or similar. OPs use case is one of the reasons why this was introduced. Downloading dependencies from privates sources is relativly common. See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information

Comment: Multi staging is also a factor to consider which makes it safe, afaik. Since only the last stage is used as final image. With go code, you most certainly use mutli staging.

Comment: @TheFool: Ah, that's handy then. I'll keep the *general* advice the way it is though. :-) (As for the staging trick, that can work in theory for sure, but anything that might leave a trace is still a concern.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

never do that, you need download the repo outside the `docker build` command, and use `COPY` to transfer these files into images, when build

Comment: yep, compile source code, build, then copy into docker file with command COPY, it's relevant and safety

thank you

Comment: If you agree, accept the answer, security is higher than others.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's most clean to use an ssh key for that. You can actually tell docker to use the config from your local ssh agent. You need to enable buildkit for this. [See the docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds).

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add /path/to/ssh-key
docker build --ssh default --tag example .
```

In your Dockerfile, you need to mount this on a specific run instruction:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh go mod download
```

That requires you adding the same ssh key to your private bitbucket repo, so that you can use it to download dependencies.

---

There are more ways to mount secrets for the lifetime of a run instruction. [See the docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information).

Answer (score 1):

For me helped add "machine github.com login USERNAME password APIKEY
" to $HOME/.netrc

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest as builder
ARG GIT_CONFIG
WORKDIR /builder/
ADD . /builder/
RUN "${GIT_CONFIG}" > $HOME/.netrc
&& CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main ./cmd/main.go
&& rm -f $HOME/.netrc

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /builder/main/ .
```

Maybe it will help you.